# How use condition in codeigniter form_dropdown?

Tags: codeigniter

Here state_list, state3 showing undefined error in form_dropdown but here I give condition, how solve this error, I also give condition both controller and model but same error occurred?

```
<?php 
if(!empty($state_list)) 
{ 
    $state_list; 
}
if(!empty($state3)) 
{ 
    $state3; 
}
$js = 'id="state"  class="form-control" onchange="get_city(this.value)" onblur="setval(this.name)"';
echo form_dropdown('state', $state_list, $state3, $js);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

load the **form helper**

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

[form helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html)

```
<?php 
 $js = 'id="state"  class="form-control" onchange="get_city(this.value)" onblur="setval(this.name)"';
if(!empty($state_list)){

echo form_dropdown('state', $state_list, $state3, $js);

}else{
  $state_list = array();
  echo form_dropdown('state', $state_list, $state3, $js);
}

?>
```

Comment: Helper already use @RajatGupta. This is blank validation if state is blank nothing will show for that I give empty condition but its not working.

Comment: Thanks @RajatGupta.

Comment: Welcome @Manoranjanpanda